# Kernel panic - not syncing: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler

Tags: kernel, timeout

I am using Windows 8.1. I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04. 
But I get this error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUS entered broadcast exception handler
```

[image: photo of laptop screen]

I try and try but can`t solve it. :(( 
Please help me.

Comment: It is a kernel bug and has been fixed in a number of ways from disconnecting CD ROM devices to updating BIOS to updating microcode. I suggest you try Ubuntu 17.10, although that is unlikely to resolve the problem, a higher kernel may be patched.

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 i5 [*3.3GHz*] Dell Optiplex Workstations running Ubuntu 16.04LTS. We do not have any CDROMs in the machines.  The BIOS is as advanced as it gets for these devices.  As a result of recent updates (kernel rev *4.4.0-134* through *4.4.0-137*) the workstations no longer boot with this error message.  Rolling back to rev *4.4.0-133* works however.  There is definitely something amiss with the newer kernel and the older machines.